# How to list all my Github repositories, public and private in the terminal with git or in Vim with Fugitive?

Tags: git, shell, ubuntu-20.04, vim-fugitive

I have a few repositories on my Github account and I am trying to pipe a list of names of all these repos (private and public) to some scripts for automating a few tasks.

What I did-

- Read a lot of QnA on this, but most answers revolve around `git remote` or similar commands that I found are irrelevant to the problem. I still checked out its examples to be sure about this. Few others answered how to list locally stored repos but that would mean cloning each of them. I believe these two don't make this a duplicate question.
- Browsed the git documentation, but nothing seemed to allow this operation
- Thought about cloning the entire account (somewhere around 7gb..) Please dont make me do this

Any ideas?

Comment: `gh` ([github-cli](https://github.com/cli/cli)) with [this alias](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/642#issuecomment-693598673) can do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible using [github's cli](https://github.com/cli/cli). For instance, on Ubuntu this works:

```
sudo snap install gh
gh auth login
```

```
$ gh repo list tpope

Showing 30 of 84 repositories in @tpope

tpope/vim-dadbod              dadbod.vim: Modern database interface for Vim                                           public        1d
tpope/vim-fugitive            fugitive.vim: A Git wrapper so awesome, it should be illegal                            public        2d
tpope/vim-unimpaired          unimpaired.vim: Pairs of handy bracket mappings                                         public        2d
tpope/vim-commentary          commentary.vim: comment stuff out                                                       public        8d
(...)
```

Integrating this into vim-fugitive would best be a separate question.

Comment: Thx.. Now I can automate to my heart's desire.. Its been 5 years.. and i forgot about it totally

Answer (score 0):

The only way to find this information is via the GitHub API (e.g., [using this API call](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-repositories-for-the-authenticated-user)), which will require an HTTP client and some JSON parsing.  Usually, this will be done via `curl` and `jq`, but you can also do it with a language such as Ruby.

This information isn't exposed by Git because Git doesn't expose the concept of having a single account on a server with multiple, discoverable repositories.  Many sites hosting repositories don't have this concept, either.  Fugitive is just a wrapper around Git, so it also doesn't have this concept, although there are extensions to support it working with GitHub that may provide this functionality.